# Stored procedure Text saving in Delphi

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010, bde

I need to create stored procedure into oracle from delphi with TQuery.
But the SQL.text is difficult to uunderstand.
Is there any way to store direct text as pl/SQL with out quotes?

```
'create or replace '+
'function WholeTableRecovery(i_tablname IN varchar) return varchar '+
'as '+
```

Is it possible with resource file

Thanks in advance

Comment: For example you can put it as the content of `TMemo` on your form, then make it hidden in runtime and just read the text from it.

There also are 3rd party non-visual components containing texts in DFM.

PS: with resource file you would have to properly save text as UTF-16 or non-Unicode for different Delphi versions. That is possible but is a nuisance. What is your real Delphi version and what do you try to accomplish and whay exactly the problem is ? 

PS: BDE is really, really deprecated today. Do think about switchign to some direct library!

Comment: What exactly you can not understand with TQuery.SQL.Text? It will be stored for you already. What is your real question?

Comment: Sure there is a way. The `SQL` property is an ordinary `TStrings` descendant, so store your SQL queries as a text resource and use the `TQuery.SQL.LoadFromStream` method for a `TResourceStream` where you'll have loaded resource with a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Delphi 2010 in the tags (I have no Delphi 7 here to test), a comfortable method would be storing the SQLs in separate textfiles, together with a RC file containing the directives for the resource compiler.
[image]

The RC files will contain the names of the resource you want to use together with the filenames containing the SQLs you want to store. The content for the example would look like this:

```
My_First_Speaking_ResourceName RCDATA "MyFirstSQL.sql"
My_Second_Speaking_ResourceName RCDATA "MySecondSQL.sql"
```

There is no need to call [BRCC32](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/BRCC32.EXE,_the_Resource_Compiler) directly if you include the resource containing RC and resulting RES :

```
{$R 'MySQLResources.res' 'resources\MySQLResources.rc'}
```

You might wrap the usage of TResourceStream for your convenience, the way shown in the example would use Strings you might also work with the stream directly as mentioned by TLama `MyQuery.SQL.LoadFromStream(rs);`

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{$R 'MySQLResources.res' 'resources\MySQLResources.rc'}

function LoadSqlResource(resourceName: string): string;
var
  rs: TResourceStream;
  sl: TStringList;
  s : string;
begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    rs := TResourceStream.Create(hinstance, resourceName, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    rs.Position := 0;
    sl.LoadFromStream(rs);
    Result := sl.Text;
  finally
    rs.Free;
  end;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure  CallOneSql(Q:TADOQuery;ResourceName:String);
begin
  Q.SQL.Text := LoadSqlResource('My_First_Speaking_ResourceName');
  Q.ExecSQL;
end;
```

With a call like `CallOneSql(MyQuery,'My_First_Speaking_ResourceName');`

Make sure to create the project, not just compile if you made changes on the RC or the SQL files.

Comment: *There is no need to call BRCC32* does Delphi 2010 IDE has a menu option to include files into resources like XE2's Project / Resources and Images ? PS. Though thanks for binary syntax of $R, did not heard of that, better for version control

Comment: @Arioch'The yes D2010 already supports  `{$R *.dres}`. Good point, you might add it as own answer. I'm just used to the proposed way, since already some of my templates and standard units are using resources independent from the projects.

Comment: after trying to port pre-Unicode DUnit to XE2 and getting a whole lot of ansi/wide troubles in RC texts i am very wary towards having texts directly in RC. You just can put them onto forms or data modules instead. Especially if both D2010 and D7 are to co-exist